# Statusline vs Rulerformat - What is the Difference?

Tags: statusline, options, ruler

What is the purpose of the `ruler`?

---

I have recently learned about the **statusline** and the **rulerformat**, and was wondering what the difference between them is.

Why does the **ruler** exist? Why can't you only use the **statusline**?
Just give it some padding to the right and you got your **ruler**, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vi didn't have windows so the user only needed *one* information device for the single buffer vi could display at a time: the "ruler".

Vim is a vi clone, therefore Vim has a "ruler".

But Vim is more than a vi clone, it is "vi improved".

Vim has windows so the Vim user's needs are more complex than those of the vi user. The Vim user needs both a per-window ruler *and* some way to visually separate windows, hence the status-line.

Since the status-line covers both needs there is no point in having the two active at the same time.

Comment: ahh okay thanks. One more question... If I try to use both, it doesn't work. One just disappears. Any Ideas why?

Comment: See my last sentence.

Comment: okay maybe I understood smth wrong, but it says `there is no point in having the two`, but it is **not** even possible... My question is why :)

Comment: When you have a status line, the ruler info is displayed in it so you still have the info. It's just displayed in a single more logical place rather than two places.

Answer (score 0):

This has confused me for a long time.

By default the statusline isn't shown if you only have 1 window open. If you do `set laststatus=2` to force it to always show it becomes a lot clearer what the statusline actually is—it's the coloured bar at the bottom of each window.

If there is a statusline then the ruler is shown in the statusline (for each window). Which makes it clearer what the ruler is—it's not the whole line, it's just the part to the right with the row/column numbers in.

If there isn't a statusline then the ruler is shown in the line at the bottom of the screen (I think it's possibly called the "command line" or "command area"?).

Comment: Omg why are people on this site always downvoting... I upvoted so you should be back to 0 :)          Thanks for further clarification^^ And yeah I was wondering that too one day and asked it here and got downvoted to oblivion so had to remove the question haha. Till this day... no idea :)

Comment: Because other people on this site always ask silly questions in weird places and someone has to do something about it.

Comment: The question was "what's the difference between the ruler and the statusline". That's literally what my answer explains.

Comment: This answer seems fine—it does contain a wandering question at the end, which could be better asked as a proper Question, but it also provides a concrete answer to what the statusline and ruler are. I don’t agree that it isn’t an answer.

Comment: Then it's an answer. Fine with me. Believe it or not, I'm not randomly bullying people, I actually wanted to *help* you get your question answered - which simply won't happen if it's trailing behind an answer.